# generating dynamic div id using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to assign unique id into HTML DIV dynamically created by jquery Ajax.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'xxx',
        data: 'xxx',
        url: 'xxx',
        success: function(data) {

                var repeatID =1;

                $.each(data.data, function(i, v){

                    repeatID++;

                    //alert(repeatID);

                    $("#divId").append('<div class="single" id="my_test_' + repeatID + '">'
                                                    +'<div class="any_name"> '+ v.Name +' </div></div>');
                });
        error:...
});
```

I need to assign a unique id into class 'single'. Inside the each loop, repeatID is increasing outside append (like if I uncomment alert and there are 3 arrays returned by server then it will give alert message for three times.). But inside append it is not increasing. All the values remain the initially assigined value, 1. So, for the three DIV I got id 'my_test_1'.

I am expecting to get 'my_test_1', 'my_test_2', 'my_test_3' if there are 3 arrays. Where I am doing the wrong?

Any solution please?

Comment: repeatID should be initiated outside the ajax method.

Comment: Are you sure? It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SdyYk/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the index parameter (in your case, `i`) as the counter. You don't need `repeatID` as the callback parameter in the `each` function comes with the functionality you desire.

```
$.each(data.data, function(i, v){
    $("#divId").append('<div class="single" id="my_test_' + (i+1) + '">'
                          +'<div class="any_name"> '+ v.Name +' </div></div>');
}
```

*I've used `(i+1)` as you seem to want it to be 1-based.*

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/3wFE4/

**More info on jQuery `each`:**
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

> jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

Comment: Hi, Jace. Thanks for your reply. But I am getting the same problem. for all the DIVs the name is 'my_test_1'. But if I make a alert before append 'alert(i);', it will make a 3 times alert 0, 1, 3! I do not understand why does 'i' not increasing inside 'append'....?

Comment: @Cart that's pretty much impossible, there's something else at play. Can you please share with me all the code in your `each` function?

Comment: Actually I am working on Phonegap. The process (you have provided) is working fine in web. The process is not working in phonegap. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting the increment after the `append()`:

```
var repeatID =1;
$.each(data.data, function(i, v){
  $("#divId").append('<div class="single" id="my_test_' + repeatID + '">'+
   '<div class="any_name"> '+ v.Name +' </div></div>');
   repeatID++;
});
```

---

Don't know about your issues but the second one is working absolutely fine for me.

#### [If you want to see this in a demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2Dzpd/)

Comment: Already I have tried both, but not working inside 'APPEND'. outside append everything works fine. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Cart added a fiddle might be helpful for you. Worked for me

Comment: Actually I am working on Phonegap. like Jase, also your process is working fine in web. The process is not working in phonegap. Thanks a lot for your help.